# What is the $TT^*$ method?

Tags: notation, harmonic-analysis, convention

So I have the following task:

> Let $T_j f(x)=\int_{\mathbb R}f(x-t)e^{it^3}\psi(2^{-j}t)\frac{dt}{t}$ for $j>0$.
>   Prove that $\|T_j f\|_2\leq\|f\|_2$.

Now the hint suggests to use the $TT^*$ method.
I am assuming that $T^*$ denotes the adjoint operator.
But what exactly is the $TT^*$ method?

Comment: Perhaps it refers to showing $\langle f,T^*Tf\rangle\le c\|f\|^2$, so then $\|Tf\|\le\|f\|$. In your case $T$ is normal, so $\|T^*f\|=\|Tf\|$ and one can use $TT^*$ instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $TT^*$ refers to a result that says that if one of

$$T,$$

or

$$T^*,$$

or

$$TT^*$$

(-and hence the name) is bounded then all of the above are bounded.
A surface level google search didn't return that many results, but you can find statements in
Stein,Shakarchi Vol IV, chapter 8 section 5(or 6?)
Muscalu and Schlag...somewhere in the middle.

You can also show that the constants, i.e, the bound $k$ in $||T f|| \leq k ||f||$ , is the same (or at least related) in all cases. 
Furthermore - see the statement in Ginibre and Velo's paper [here](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022123685711196) , which is the most general statement of the result I know of- we can use combinations of operators in context.

In your case, I suggest computing $T_jT_j^*$ and seeing if that is easier to bound, and if the constant that gives you the bound is $1$, as this is equivalent to what you are trying to show by the "$TT^*$ theorem". I'm not sure what context you are in and therefore what inner product you should compute in, but if the hint is to use $TT^*$ then
this should at least be doable...